# CSS - Image scaling but from the right?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, image-resizing

```css
article img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/84FnVcK/Group.png">
</article>
```

Is it possible to keep the 'This needs visible' text on the image to stay there? So the image scales from a different angle? Note: The this needs visible is actually a logo on some images and the logo falls off when the window is getting smaller (responsive)

**Here the text falls off**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving it [`object-position: left center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position), much like `background-position`, it determines the anchor point when the image needs to be scaled.

```css
article img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: left center;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/84FnVcK/Group.png">
</article>
```